# Mean and variance of the Variant of Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, variance

We know that the normal form of Bernoulli distribution is, X = 1 with probability p and X = 0 with probability 1 - p. But what is the p.m.f of Bernoulli distribution if $X \in {-1, 1}$?

My approach is, the probability equals p if X = 1 and $p^{-1} (1-p)^2$ if X = -1. Is it correct?

So, to find the mean, using the definition and yields something like $p - \frac{(1-p)^2}{p}$. It seems strange, I am wondering if it is correct or not.

Comment: You mean, what is the PMF of the Bernoulli distribution if the "fail" is encoded as $-1$ instead of $0$? It's $p$ for $1$ and $(1-p)$ for $-1$, that's it.

Comment: Yes @Ian, but what is the mean and var? I get confused during the calculation

Comment: A shortcut way to get them is to write it as $2X-1$ where $X$ is Bernoulli, then the mean is $2\mu-1=2p-1$ and the variance is $4\sigma^2=4p(1-p)$.

Comment: I am sorry, would you mind to explain how to write it as 2X - 1? @Ian

Comment: $f(x)=2x-1$ sends $0$ to $-1$ and $1$ to $1$, so you can apply it to a normal Bernoulli to represent your distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ian points out in the comments, any random variable with 2-point support is just a scaled and shifted Bernoulli random variable. That is, if $X$ has 2 point support $\{a,b\}$ and assigns mass $1-p$ to $a$ and mass $p$ to $b$, then we can write

$$X=a+(b-a)B$$

where $B$ is a standard Bernoulli random variable. From here, the mean and variance can be computed (the mean should be immediate to begin with from the definition):

$$E[X]=a+(b-a)E[B]=a+(b-a)p=a(1-p)+bp\\
V(X)=(b-a)^2V(B)=(b-a)^2p(1-p).$$